# How do we show that the sequences is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

how do we prove that if $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $s_{n}/n = L$, $L \neq 0$ then the sequence $s_n$ is not bounded?

Comment: Try by contradiction. (hint: squeeze theorem) Also, you should show your effort.

Comment: If $s_n$ were bounded, what do you think the $L$ will be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supose that $s_{n}$ is bounded so exists $M\ge 0$ that $|s_{n}|\le M.$ We have
$$0\le\frac{|s_{n}|}{n}\le \frac{M}{n}\to0$$ When $n\to\infty$, that implies that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{|s_{n}|}{n}=0$ What it is a contradiction, we had that L$\neq 0$